# Error Baking Fluids Simulation in Flip Fluids add-on Blender

Tags: animation, add-on, fluid-simulation, baking, error

[image: System console screenshot]I installed the flip-fluid addon from a different website and not the official one (i cant afford the original one). It does seem to work fine but when i try to do the simplest fluid animation in blender and click on the bake button, it gives a message "Error Baking Fluid Simulation". I will provide some images of my problem.

blender version: 2.93.5

[image: screenshot of console]

[image: image of my screen in blender when i try to bake]

Comment: There's a message in the info log "See system console for error info."  You need to open the terminal window and post a screenshot of those error messages

Comment: As mentioned above, the console window will show the error (Window > Toggle System Console). When using Blender 2.93, make sure that you are using a compatible version of the FLIP Fluids addon. FLIP Fluids v1.0.9b or later is required for Blender 2.93 compatibility. Versions older than this can result in these types of immediate error popups.

Comment: Ok I added the screenshot

Comment: it does say 1.0.9b so i guess its not the version is it?

Answer (score 1):

From the error screenshot, it looks like the unofficial distributor may have packaged the FLIP Fluids addon in a way that causes it not to function correctly.

The folder that contains the addon's scripts must be named `flip_fluids_addon`, but from the screenshot it looks like it has been renamed to `~Get Your Graphic Files`. The fix is to rename that folder to `flip_fluids_addon`.

More info on how to verify a correct installation can be found in this documentation: [FLIP Fluids Addon - Addon Installation Troubleshooting](https://github.com/rlguy/Blender-FLIP-Fluids/wiki/Addon-Installation-Troubleshooting)

Comment: omg thank you so so much! you fixed the problem completely!

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to download this version, you shouldn't have any problems. On the site there is the relevant documentation and a lot of important information.

https://github.com/rlguy/Blender-FLIP-Fluids